# Adding filetransfer in PhoneGap breaks build

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to upload a video to a server in PhoneGap. The code is running in terms of opening the camera dialog and recording the video, but then the JS in the index.html file requires use of the FileTransfer plugin.

Adding this plugin from the phonegap command line results in the following error...

/platforms/ios/ManUtd/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer/CDVFileTransfer.m:23:9: 'CDVLocalFilesystem.h' file not found

The html file is the documented code from the PhoneGap website

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
<title>Capture Video</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Called when capture operation is finished
        //
        function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
            var i, len;
            for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
            }
        }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function captureError(error) {
        var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
        navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function captureVideo() {
        // Launch device video recording application,
        // allowing user to capture up to 2 video clips
        navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 2});
    }

    // Upload files to server
    function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
        var ft = new FileTransfer(),
        path = mediaFile.fullPath,
        name = mediaFile.name;

        ft.upload(path,
                  "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
                  function(result) {
                  console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                  console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
                  },
                  function(error) {
                  console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
                  },
                  { fileName: name });   
    }

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="captureVideo();">Capture Video</button> <br>
</body>
</html>
```

I have run both these commands and both result in the code breaking

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git

$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git
```

I am targeting iOS only at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be related to the whole PhoneGap/Cordova thing.

Creating a new project using Cordova instead of PhoneGap, has sorted the problem. It appears as if the FileTransfer API is broken if you start an app using PhoneGap.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem - I deleted 'file' plugin, 'file-transfer' plugin and re-add them again, and everything worked